# Pound sign(£) in sql query result

Tags: sql

I wanted to have pound sign in sql query result as £ , but when I am executing this query, it is not displaying expected symbol:

```
  select chr(169) from dual;
```

Actual result is: �
Expected Result:£

Comment: what database do you use ?

Comment: Which SQL client tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
select '£' from dual;
select concat('£' , 500) from dual;
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

There is no ASCII value for £ sign  that why it's not showing pound sign but if you want to show pound your need to change your `NLS_TERRITORY` setting then use below

```
select to_char(123, 'L999,999.00') from dual;
```

right now it will show $ because oracle by default setting is american $
[list of parameter for NLS_TERRITORY](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4039558.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
SELECT CHAR(0163) FROM TABLE_NAME;
```